# ¿Cómo puedo añadir más elementos a un archivo XML de dom4j sin sobreescribirlo?

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

Básicamente tengo un problema con los archivos xml de java, estos no los entiendo(bueno sí, pero son largos). Ya probé los con dom4j, y realmente no supe como añadir más elementos sin que se sobrescribiera después de crear un archivo y cerrarlo una vez se ingresen los datos

```
static void OpcNewProduct(){
    var In = new Scanner(System.in);
    try{
        Document document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
        Element Datos = document.addElement("Datos");
        
        Element Registro = Datos.addElement("Registro");
        Element Historial = Datos.addElement("Historial");

        Element Producto = Registro.addElement("Producto");
        System.out.println("Si desea cancelar, ponga '/leave'\nen cualquier momento\n");
        for(Map<String, String> Atributo : Propertys.values()){
            String Propiedad;
            do{
                System.out.println("Ingrese "+Atributo.get("Propiedad"));
                Propiedad = In.nextLine();
                if(Propiedad.equalsIgnoreCase("/leave")) return;
                System.out.println(!Propiedad.matches(Atributo.get("Regex")) ? "Caracteres incorrectos" : "");
            }while(!Propiedad.matches(Atributo.get("Regex")));
            Producto.addAttribute(Atributo.get("Propiedad"), Propiedad);
        }
        try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("output.xml")) {
            XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter(fileWriter, OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint());
            writer.write( document );
            writer.close();
        }
        
    }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para que no sobrescribas el archivo en la modificación hay un segundo constructor de la clase `FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append)`, para especificar que quieres agregar texto al archivo debes de pasar `true` ya que por defecto el constructor que usas `FileWriter(String fileName)` usa false.

```
try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("output.xml", true)) {
    XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter(fileWriter, OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint());
    writer.write( document );
    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: ciertamente ya no se sustituye, pero se crea otro "documento" en el mismo archivo. Básicamente quiero guardar más elementos en el elemento "Registro", pero cuando cierro el archivo y lo abro para agregar otro elemento en "Registro", se sustituye.

Comment: En ese casos solo puedes leer todo el documento don dom4j y agregar nuevos elementos al documento de dom4j y sobreescribir todo el archivo con las modificaciones. Ten en cuenta que el archivo ya ocupa un espacio en el disco y no puedes solo agregar elementos y esperar que la memoria que ocupa se expanda.